# Solving the Friedmann Equation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, general-relativity, cosmology, metric-tensor, space-expansion

Through substituting for values of $\rho$ and $k$, I have:

$$H^2=\left(\frac{\dot{a}}{a}\right)^2=\frac{8\pi G C}{3a^4} + \frac{\Lambda c^2}{3}$$

$a=a(t)$, and $a(t=0)=0$. Note that $C$ is a constant of integration, which I calculated in the derivation of $\rho=Ca^{-6}$. introduced from the substitution to eliminate $\rho$ - it is not the same as $c$.

Further to this,

$$\frac{\ddot{a}}{a}=\frac{-16 \pi GC}{3a^6}+\frac{\Lambda c^2}{3}$$

However, this universe is dominated by a fluid where $p=\rho c^2$. Hence;

$$H^2=(\frac{\dot{a}}{a})^2=\frac{8\pi G C}{3a^4}$$
and
$$\frac{\ddot{a}}{a}=\frac{-16 \pi GC}{3a^6}$$

I'm not sure if it would be possible to integrate the second of those two, and substitute the result into the first to get an equation in $a$? I'm also not sure that those two equations even hold.

I'm not really sure as to how to get the 'temporal dependence of $a$, and can't manage to integrate or solve it any other way myself. I've left out everything done beforehand, though a lot of it is available in the chat or my other questions.

Comment: you need to use the other Friedmann equation as well to truly nail down the temporal dependence of $a$. You need an equation with $\ddot a$. Using that, you can see that, at late times, $a(t)=e^{Ht}$. At early times, it gets a bit messy

Comment: Hi all. I've discussed this question extensively in the H-Bar, and have done alot of work to get to this point, mainly with John Rennie. It's not a homework question, and I believe that the amount of work put into it so far, as well as prior discussion merits it being re-opened. Please consider this! Thanks.

Comment: Jim, I'm not sure what I'm exactly trying to find - what form am I looking for?

Comment: Actually, if you allow $t=0$ to represent the present, you'll find that $a(t)=e^{Ht}$ is a good general approximation

Comment: Hi Noah P. If you haven't already done so, please take a minute to read the definition of when to use the [homework-and-exercises](http://physics.stackexchange.com/tags/homework-and-exercises/info) tag, and the Phys.SE [policy](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/714) for homework-like problems.

Comment: The on-topicness of homework-like questions like this one depends not on the amount of work you may or may not have put into it, but on whether the question asks a more specific and conceptual question than "What do I do now?" or "How to solve this equation?". Which is not the case in this case.

Comment: @ACuriousMind I have my own ideas, but I'm not sure how to proceed - would this being put in an edit help?

Comment: @ACuriousMind Done so anyway